# Latex !TEX code

Tags: latex

The most part of the LaTEX IDE (I use texStudio) allow to use `!TEX` codes to change the behavior of the compilation. E.g.:

```
%%!TEX root = main.tex
```

Adding this in the beginning of each  file include at `main.tex` by `\include{*}` directive will make the IDE compile always by `main.tex`, even if you try to compile by a included file.

I know that  have more resource than this. Someone have the full list of `!TEX`comands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeXstudio has a list of its available magic comments / Advanced headers at http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION_TEXCOM.

They include `spellcheck` and `encoding`, and ways to set how the file is built (write a script, or set the `program` and a program to generate the bibliography).

Answer (score 3):

A list of which editors support which magic comments (taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84687/36296)

```
              E P R S
TeXShop       x x x x
TeXStudio     x x x x
TextMate      ? x x ?
TeXworks      x x x x
SublimeText   o x x x
Atom          o x x o
Vim (vimtex)  o x x o
Overleaf      ? x ? ?
              | | | |
x = yes       | | | Spellcheck
o = no        | | Root
? = ?         | Program
              Encoding
```